# Proving That a $1 \times 1$ Matrix has a Rank of $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have an assignment that asks me to prove something but I've hit a roadblock.

Let $u$ be a $3 \times 1$ matrix with $u_{1}$, $u_{2}$, and $u_{3}$. Let $v$ be a $3 \times 1$ matrix with $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$. Assume that $u_{1} \neq 0$, $v_{1} \neq 0$.
Let $A = uv^{T}$
Prove that $\text{rank}(A) = 1$.

$v^{T} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and multiplying it with $u$ ($u$ is before $v^T$) gives:

$1 \times 1$ matrix $A = ( u_{1}v_{1} + u_{2}v_{2} + u_{3}v_{3} )$

Where do I go from here to figure out the rank? I'm not sure if the basis is the resulting scalar since $1 \times 1$ matrixes are scalars according to my teacher. If this were true then I could just say the dimension of $A$ is $1$ and thus the rank is $1$, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Sorry about the shoddy display, I don't know how to use TeX language.

EDIT: The $1 \times 1$ matrix I found is incorrect. $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: Um, actually, I think you have the dimensions wrong; $A$ is actually a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: You're right about that, whoops.

Comment: We have a MathJax tutorial. I have edited your post to add in math formatting. You can learn more about how to format your posts here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Please take the time to learn how to do so, as it helps us better help you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I wrote this answer under the assumption that $A$ was a $1\times 1$ matrix (as originally stated in the question), but that doesn't follow from the problem statement.

It's not the dimension of $A$ that is $1$ (matrices don't have that kind of dimension), but rather the dimension of the column space of $A$ is $1$. Other than that, you're good!

[I would be a bit reluctant to always think of $1\times 1$ matrices as scalars, though, because matrices have a lot of operations that become uninteresting on scalars. It is a bit awkward to think about the column space of a scalar, for example.]

Comment: The fact that I'm dealing with a 1 x 1 matrix doesn't matter much at all?

Comment: Nope: rank is rank is rank. The dimension of the column space is 1, and therefore the rank is 1. What it does get you is a (super) easy check of linear independence and spanning-ness, though :)

Comment: All right, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\langle1,-1,0\rangle$ and $v=\langle1,1,0\rangle$.  Then rank of $A$ is zero.